blazor project when publish IIS,then show razor.js not found
This is the case. I use blazor ssr written in .net7.0. There is a page composed of razor and razor.js. There are no exceptions in local debugging. After publishing to IIS, it prompts that the js file cannot be found. How to solve it. The browser console prompt is as follows: xxxx/xxxx.razor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
How to solve, bother me

This issue didn't occur in my side, could you please help confirm whether you set the path to js file correctly? In my side, I have Pages/Index.razor component, and I create Pages/Index.razor.js, then I added <script src="Pages/Index.razor.js"></script> in _Host.cshtml. After I published my app to folder and running the site in local IIS, I can see in the published Directory, there's wwwroot -> Pages -> Index.razor.js, which matching the description from this document.

When the app is published, the framework automatically moves the script to the web root. Scripts are moved to bin/Release/{TARGET FRAMEWORK MONIKER}/publish/wwwroot/{PATH}/{COMPONENT}.razor.js, where the placeholders are:  -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/location-of-javascript?view=aspnetcore-7.0#load-a-script-from-an-external-javascript-file-js-collocated-with-a-component

Here’s the directory where my Index.razor.js lies after I published the app to IIS : https://i.sstatic.net/jtYA50HF.png

hello,Tiny Wang, in _Host.cshtml  ，Is this step necessary? in my razor，This is how I quoted js：var moduel = await JS.InvokeAsync("import", "./Pages/TravelPages/UploadForm.razor.js");

yes, your approach is ok as well, searching for A better approach for production apps is to use JS modules. in the link I shared to see more detail if you faced issue.

But with my method, there is no problem when debugging locally, but problems arise when publishing to IIS, prompting that the js file cannot be found.

I had a test with the sample codes shared in the link and it worked well in my side, I can see the .razor.js file in wwwroot folder after publishing the app to local folder, and then the website host in IIS could also hit this js too. https://i.sstatic.net/iS2JsFj8.png

could you pls help confirm whether the UploadForm.razor.js file existed in wwwroot/Pages/TravelPages directory under your publish folder?   https://i.sstatic.net/tCYL2zjy.png
